# ggplot/scatterplot of rank in one year against rank in a different year

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

This would seem to be rather simple. Please point me to a duplicate if you know one. With data arranged in long form with the `melt()` function of package `reshape2` (author: Hadley Wickham) and with `ggplot()` command of package `ggplot2` (author: Hadley Wickham), **I want to plot a variable's id ordered by the rank of its value in 2009 against its rank of 2007**.

My best shot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(
    x = reorder(subset(id, year == "2007"), subset(rank, year == "2007")), 
    y = reorder(subset(id, year == "2009"), subset(rank, year == "2009")))) + 
geom_point()
```

[image]

In the plot above, the dots lie on the 45-degree line instead of on `(id,id)` intersection (e.g. HSBC,HSBC). The ids are ordered as intended <strike>along the x-axis, but in the reverse order along the y-axis</strike>.

Note: My ultimate purpose is to make a bubble chart with the dot size proportional to the value and the variable labels and values printed next to the circles.

#### Data

```
head(df)
##                        id year value rank
## 13              Citigroup 2007   255    1
## 15                   HSBC 2007   215    2
## 14              JP Morgan 2007   165    3
## 2  Royal Bank of Scotland 2007   120    4
## 9                     UBS 2007   116    5
## 12              Santander 2007   116    6

df <- structure(list(id = c("Citigroup", "HSBC", "JP Morgan", "Royal Bank of Scotland", 
"UBS", "Santander", "BNP Paribas", "Goldman Sachs", "Unicredit", 
"Barclays", "Societe Generale", "Deutsche Bank", "Credit Suisse", 
"Credit Agricole", "Morgan Stanley", "HSBC", "JP Morgan", "Santander", 
"UBS", "Goldman Sachs", "BNP Paribas", "Credit Suisse", "Societe Generale", 
"Unicredit", "Citigroup", "Credit Agricole", "Morgan Stanley", 
"Deutsche Bank", "Barclays", "Royal Bank of Scotland"), year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2007", 
"2009"), class = "factor"), value = c(255, 215, 165, 120, 116, 
116, 108, 100, 93, 91, 80, 76, 75, 67, 49, 97, 85, 64, 35, 35, 
32.5, 27, 26, 26, 19, 17, 16, 10.3, 7.4, 4.6), rank = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)), .Names = c("id", "year", "value", 
"rank"), row.names = c(13L, 15L, 14L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 30L, 29L, 27L, 24L, 26L, 22L, 25L, 20L, 
23L, 28L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
## Data Source: A lecture handout by professor Andrei Shleifer of Harvard university, with data source quoted as J.P. Morgan and dated February 2009.
```

Comment: Hmm although this is a nice reproducible example and it's also well documented, I fail to see where the chart should go. I mean, take e.g. Unicredit, which has the same rank in both years - do you want to overplot two dots of different sizes at the same position? And do you wally want to have the id info on x, y and besides the points? Maybe add a small sketch that shows what the result should look like?

Comment: @lukeA, yes for your first question: overplot two dots (but they will be circles of different diameters after I'm done), but no to the second question: will keep the id label in one place only, after I'm done. Here, on page 19, is the inspiration for this: one circle inside another (I've got that bit working already), to which I want to add a "correlation" type layout. Thanks!  https://www.princeton.edu/bcf/newsevents/events/lectures-in-finance/Princeton_Lecture1Shleifer.pdf

Comment: Is this pointing to the right direction: ``library(tidyr); library(dplyr);df <- dfold %>% select(-value) %>% spread(year, rank) %>% right_join(dfold %>% select(-rank), by="id"); ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(id, `2007`), y = reorder(id, -`2009`), size=value)) + geom_point(data=subset(df, year==2007), colour="green", alpha=.5) + geom_point(data=subset(df, year==2009), colour="blue", alpha=.5) + scale_size(range=c(1, 40))``? `dfold` is your data frame.

Comment: @lukeA, yep that answers the question. I haven't learned to use ``tidyr`` and ``dplyr`` (yet), so there's a few new things in here, but once the dataframe is in the appropriate format, the rest is very clear. Please do make it an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think Hendrik's answer hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your data is in a "too long" format, i.e. your x values (rank in 2007) and y values (rank in 2009) have ended up in the same column. Perhaps it is easy for you to change this upstream in the data massage steps not shown in the post.

Anyway, *given* the data in the post, I would start by converting it to a wider format (here using `data.table::dcast`), in order to have x and y values in separate columns:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- dcast(setDT(df), id ~ year, value.var = c("value", "rank"))
head(df2)
#                 id value_2007 value_2009 rank_2007 rank_2009
# 1:     BNP Paribas        108       32.5         7         6
# 2:        Barclays         91        7.4        10        14
# 3:       Citigroup        255       19.0         1        10
# 4: Credit Agricole         67       17.0        14        11
# 5:   Credit Suisse         75       27.0        13         7
# 6:   Deutsche Bank         76       10.3        12        13
```

Then plotting is rather straightforward:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = rank_2007, y = rank_2009, label = id)) +        
  geom_text(vjust = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value_2007), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value_2009), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Of course, lots of possibilities for prettification (label positioning, scale of the point size et c), but that's another story.

Comment: That's great Henrik, thanks. Yes I can change the data format upstream. I got into a habit of using long-form data because I read somewhere that's what ``ggplot`` likes. I was expecting there would be a simple manipulation to be able to use the long-format data directly, but if you're recommending making it wide, that's what I'll take from this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

lukeA (in the comments section) and Henrik offered some great suggestions and answers to my question. Thanks! Here I want to show, as a follow-up, how I was able to combine their suggestions to make a bubble chart with a rank-correlation visual:

[image]

[image]

The first plot uses `geom_point()` combined with `colour` and `size`, while the second plot uses `geom_point()` combined with `fill` and `size` instead, using the `shape = 21` argument to get a hollow circle printed in the legend. I found the `size` legend bubbles filled with black to be a little too overwhelming visually.

For some reason, the `name` argument of the legends did not print, which is a situation I have not encountered before and which I cannot explain. Perhaps more tweaking needed with colors and shapes... Comments welcome!

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("HSBC", "JP Morgan", "Santander", "UBS", 
"Goldman Sachs", "BNP Paribas", "Credit Suisse", "Unicredit", 
"Societe Generale", "Citigroup", "Credit Agricole", "Morgan Stanley", 
"Deutsche Bank", "Barclays", "Royal Bank of Scotland"), value.2007 = c(215L, 
165L, 116L, 116L, 100L, 108L, 75L, 93L, 80L, 255L, 67L, 49L, 
76L, 91L, 120L), value.2009 = c(97, 85, 64, 35, 35, 32.5, 27, 
26, 26, 19, 17, 16, 10.3, 7.4, 4.6), rank.2007 = c(2, 3, 6, 5, 
8, 7, 13, 9, 11, 1, 14, 15, 12, 10, 4), rank.2009 = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)), .Names = c("id", 
"value.2007", "value.2009", "rank.2007", "rank.2009"), row.names = c(15L, 
14L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L), class = "data.frame")


## Comments:
# 1. properly scale bubbles in bubble-chart:
v1 <- min(df$value.2007, df$value.2009)
v2 <- max(df$value.2007, df$value.2009)
# use + scale_size(range = c(v1, v2)/10) or similar
# 2. increase the size of points in the legend
# with + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
# 3. add a name to the legend guides: FAIL!
# + scale_size(name = "Market Cap ($bn)", range = c(v1, v2)/10)
# + scale_color_manual(name = "Year", values = c("royalblue", "forestgreen")) 

# Version 1. solid shape with colour
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = rank.2007, y = rank.2009, label = id)) +        
    geom_point(aes(size = value.2007, colour = "2007"), alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_point(aes(size = value.2009, colour = "2009"), alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_text(size = 4, vjust = -5) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 17), breaks = seq(1, 16, 2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 17), breaks = seq(1, 16, 2)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("royalblue", "forestgreen")) +
    scale_size(range = c(v1, v2)/10) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10))) +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab("Rank by Market Capitalization in 2007") +
    ylab("Rank by Market Capitalization in 2009") +
    ggtitle("Market Capitalization Before and After the Crisis \n(Selected Banks: 2009 versus 2007)") +
    theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical") +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.key = element_blank())
p

ggsave(p, file = "p1.jpg", width = 12, height = 10)

# Version 2: hollow shape with fill
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = rank.2007, y = rank.2009, label = id)) +        
    geom_point(aes(size = value.2007, fill = "2007"), 
               shape = 21, alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_point(aes(size = value.2009, fill = "2009"), 
               shape = 21, alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_text(size = 4, vjust = -5) +
    scale_size(name = "Market Cap ($bn)", range = c(v1, v2)/10) +
    scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + # combined with shape=21
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 17), breaks = seq(1, 16, 2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 17), breaks = seq(1, 16, 2)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Year", values = c("royalblue", "forestgreen")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10))) +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab("Rank by Market Capitalization in 2007") +
    ylab("Rank by Market Capitalization in 2009") +
    ggtitle("Market Capitalization Before and After the Crisis \n(Selected Banks: 2009 versus 2007)") +
    theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical") +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.key = element_blank())
p

ggsave(p, file = "p2.jpg", width = 12, height = 10)
```

Comment: Oh and there appears to be no way to control the order of the legend guides, with ``color`` appearing before ``size`` in the first plot, but after in the second plot, for reasons unknown.